# Modification of xml config file results in one line file

Tags: c#, xml

I have a program that allows the user to open xml files and edit them, then save them. The thing is, when I open a config file, (.exe.config), it saves and overwrites properly but the whole file loses its formatting and becomes one huge, long, single line. Of course with my program the user will never see that it is one line, so it is not a major problem with the functionality of my program, but does anyone know how to keep the format of the configuration xml file as it was? When I open it I'm simply changing the setting values, nothing more. I did not do anything to the format/indentation to my knowledge. Or perhaps have some insight as to why it is doing this?

Many thanks!

Tf.rz

EDIT:
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class ProgramConfig : Form
    {
        public ProgramConfig()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private XmlDocument m_XmlDoc;

        private FileStream fIn;
        private StreamReader sr;
        private StreamWriter sw;

        private OrderedDictionary m_Settings;

        private int m_savecounter = 0;

        private void ProgramConfig_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                textBox1.Text = "File open: " + GatewayConfiguration.Properties.Settings.Default.Config;
                int index = 0;
                loadconfigfile(GatewayConfiguration.Properties.Settings.Default.Config);
                string[] keys = new string[m_Settings.Keys.Count];
                m_Settings.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);
                string[] values = new string[m_Settings.Values.Count];
                m_Settings.Values.CopyTo(values, 0);

                BindingList<KeyValueType> list = new BindingList<KeyValueType>();
                for (index = 0; index < m_Settings.Count; index++)
                {
                    list.Add(new KeyValueType(keys[index], values[index].ToString()));
                }
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
                dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Key";
                dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "key";
                dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Value";
                dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "value";

                var source = new BindingSource();
                source.DataSource = list;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
                for (index = 0; index < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; index++)
                {
                    // Auto resize while keeping user resize true.
                    dataGridView1.Columns[index].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
                    int initialAutoSizeWidth = dataGridView1.Columns[index].Width;
                    dataGridView1.Columns[index].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.NotSet;
                    dataGridView1.Columns[index].Width = initialAutoSizeWidth;
                }
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
                dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "New Value";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                textBox1.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        private void loadAppSettings()
        {
            m_Settings = new OrderedDictionary();
            XmlNodeList nl = m_XmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("setting");
            foreach (XmlNode node in nl)
            {
                try
                {
                    m_Settings.Add(node.Attributes["name"].Value, node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        public void loadconfigfile(string configfile)
        {
            if (File.Exists(configfile))
            {
                m_XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                GatewayConfiguration.Properties.Settings.Default.Config = configfile;
                GatewayConfiguration.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

                fIn = new FileStream(configfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                sr = new StreamReader(fIn);
                sw = new StreamWriter(fIn);
                try
                {
                    m_XmlDoc.LoadXml(sr.ReadToEnd());
                    m_XmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
                    loadAppSettings();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException(configfile + " does not exist.");
            }
        }

        private void SaveAppSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Overwrite the old values with the new values?", "Save Settings?", buttons);
            if (result == DialogResult.No)
            {
                return;
            }
            int index = 0;
            string[] keys = new string[m_Settings.Keys.Count];
            m_Settings.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);
            for (index = 0; index < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; index++)
            {
                if ((string)dataGridView1[2, index].Value != string.Empty)
                {
                    setAppSetting(keys[index], (string)dataGridView1[2, index].Value);
                }
            }
            textBox1.Text = "Settings Saved. You may now exit.";
            m_savecounter++;
            dataGridView1.Update();
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }

        public void setAppSetting(string name, string newValue)
        {
            if (!m_Settings.Contains(name))
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Setting {0} does not exists in {1}", name, GatewayConfiguration.Properties.Settings.Default.Config));
            }
            else
            {
                if (newValue == null || m_Settings[name].ToString() == newValue)
                {
                    return;
                }
                m_Settings[name] = newValue;
                m_XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//setting[@name='" + name + "']").ChildNodes[0].InnerXml = newValue;
                fIn.SetLength(0);
                sw.Write(m_XmlDoc.InnerXml);
                sw.Flush();
            }
        }

        public class KeyValueType
        {
            private string _key;
            public string Key
            { 
                get 
                {
                    return _key;
                }
            }

            private string _value;
            public string Value
            {
                get
                {
                    return _value;
                }
            }

            public KeyValueType(string key, string value)
            {
                _key = key;
                _value = value;
            }
        }

        private void ProgramConfig_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (m_savecounter == 0)
            {
                MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("You have not saved, still want to exit?", "Exit?", buttons);
                if (result == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
            }
            sw.Close();
            sr.Close();
            fIn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to show us the code you're using to save the file.

Comment: It's impossible to know how to help you without some code, or at least some reference to what class(es) you're using to parse the XML.

Comment: @Joe White: the code is now posted. My bad!

Comment: @tf.rz: The code is incomplete. What type is `m_XmlDoc` and what is the code that instantiates it?

Comment: @Joe White: Oh dear, it seems control A control C failed me. That's all the code in the project, m_XmlDoc is a XmlDocument. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `XmlDocument` you can set the [`PreserveWhitespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace.aspx) property to true - it defaults to false if not set.

The equivalent for `XDocument` is the [`Load()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538371.aspx) overload with `LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was wondering where should I put that statement? Should I put it right after I load the xmlDocument? `m_XmlDoc.LoadXml(sr.ReadToEnd())` and right after i have `m_XmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;`

Comment: @tf.rz: The `PreserveWhitespace` link above points to the msdn page which has a sample for usage. Set the property right *before* you load the document.

Comment: Hello again, I've tried your suggestion and unfortunately my xpath is messed up and I think all I am getting for the values of the settings are boxes, which I believe correspond to carriage returns and newline escape characters. Should I modify my xpath to get the nodes or is there something else I can change as well? =)

Comment: @tf.rz: Not sure I understand your comment - it would be good if you could provide a minimal code sample that compiles and illustrates the problem.

Comment: My apologies for not being specific, but Ive answered my own question there and have a different problem now. Does setting that property PreserveWhitespace to true make the xml document read-only? Because now I cannot edit the innertext like i would in `m_XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//setting[@name='" + name + "']").ChildNodes[0].InnerXml = newValue;`